# Click a Div Dropdown Function Not Working on IPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iphone

Edit: It turns out the problem wasn't necessarily due to my code. When I click the link in my Nav bar it goes to mobile/folder/page.html on every browser except Chrome. When I click the link in chrome it opens to /mobile/#/mobile/folder/page.html for some reason and that's why it doesn't work.  If I go directly to the page it works fine.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

This code works in every browser for me and works on android phones but isn't working on iphone.  I have tried adding tap and touch instead of onClick, toggle instead of hide and show, adding onclick to css, and adding cursor:pointer to css as well but I can't find a solution.  Maybe I am adding them wrong but I am not sure.  Please help!

https://jsfiddle.net/anthonyparrett7/0bmw79yw/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
/* Question and Answer Dropdowns */     
$(".dropdown-link").click(function(e) {         
  e.preventDefault();
  var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');
  $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
    if ($div.is(":visible")) {
        $div.hide()
    }  else {
       $div.show();
    }
});
$(document).click(function(e){
    var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length
    if (!p) {
          $(".dropdown-container").hide();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle, hope it helps https://jsfiddle.net/0bmw79yw/6/

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the function properly on page load.

Try starting it with `$(document).ready(function()` instead of `$(document).on("pageinit", "#page-container", function()`

See this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
    var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');
    $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
    if ($div.is(":visible")) {
      $div.hide()
    } else {
      $div.show();
    }
  });
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length
    if (!p) {
      $(".dropdown-container").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <div class="dropdown-link">
    <h4>What is a Question?</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <p>Bla bla bla blablablabla words Ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
  <div class="dropdown-link">
    <h4>What is a Question 2?</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
    <p>Bla bla bla blablablabla words Ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something simplier like:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
      $(".dropdown-container").hide();
      $(this).next(".dropdown-container").toggle();
    });
    $(document).click(function(e) {
      var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length
      if (!p) {
        $(".dropdown-container").hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: The demo appears to be the same code as what I have.  I tried the code from your Answer and it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Sorry my bad, forgot to save the updated fiddle and ended up sharing the wrong code... I've updated my answer and the fiddle ;-)